# DataGrip stuck on "connecting to database..."

Tags: amazon-redshift, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I try to connect to Redshift Using JetBrain DataGrip, after I fill in the datasource information (host, db, username, password etc) and try **Test Connection** I saw that there is a background task spawn up and prompts "Connecting to database..." and stuck there forever.

I'm able to connect with SQL WorkbenchJ with same datasource information.

Has anyone encounter this issue?

Comment: it should work fine i use all the time, postgresql driver, change port to 5439

Comment: Can you please send logs to maxim.sobolevskiy/at/jetbrains.com?

Comment: And 'hosts' file as well please.

Comment: It turns out I have this line in my host file:

127.0.0.1   myhostname.xxx.xxxxxx.com
I change it to:

127.0.0.1   localhost
It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I have this line in my host file:

```
127.0.0.1   myhostname.xxx.xxxxxx.com
```

I change it to:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

It's working now.

Comment: Sorry but what is the location of the host file you're talking about?